# Saving retrieved documents from API

Tags: python, download

I am currently trying to download a cif file from materialsproject.org which is only possible via an API. They told me to use Mybinder.org to run their code:

```
from mp_api.client import MPRester
from pymatgen.analysis.diffraction.xrd import XRDCalculator
from pymatgen.symmetry.analyzer import SpacegroupAnalyzer

with MPRester(api_key='8dI6UZHs3Nc9lxTp75RrJcPdwvPn6jZb') as mpr:
    # first retrieve the relevant structure
    structure = mpr.get_structure_by_material_id('mp-980949')

# important to use the conventional structure to ensure
# that peaks are labelled with the conventional Miller indices
sga = SpacegroupAnalyzer(structure)
conventional_structure = sga.get_conventional_standard_structure()

# this example shows how to obtain an XRD diffraction pattern
# these patterns are calculated on-the-fly from the structure
calculator = XRDCalculator(wavelength='CuKa')
pattern = calculator.get_pattern(conventional_structure)
```

When I run the code it tells me "Retrieving MaterialsDoc documents: 100%". How do I go on from here? I assume it has only retrieved the document, not downloaded it yet onto my pc. I have exactly zero knowledge about programming and APIs. It also doesn't need to download as a cif file. A simple txt. File would also help. I could create my own cif file from that.

I tried running the code from my PC with Python, but nothing really happens. After using Google to find out ways to download data retrieved from APIs I copied some code that others used to download retrieved data, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Ideally, you'd share the URL link to the mybinder launch URL or the repo they directed to you so that concrete advice can be offered that reflects the environment provided in the temporary session. The MyBinder service only works with public repositories so you wouldn't be providing anything they haven't shared. As written, you seem to know what to do: " I assume it has only retrieved the document, not downloaded it yet onto my pc." Yes, the temporary sessions served by the MyBinder service are running on remote machines. So you need to download anything you get or make back to your computer.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I finally stumbled upon it. https://github.com/materialsproject/binder

Answer (score 1):

I have already worked on that code so as to plot XRD pattern data. In order to access the result of this code, I used the method 'as_dict()' to get the elements of the last variable as a dictionary and, then, converted it into a pandas dataframe using 'pd.DataFrame.from_dict'. Therefore, I think the following code could work for you:

```
df_pattern = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pattern.as_dict())
df_pattern
```

The dataframe contains an x and y columns which can be plotted with matplotlib as a bar graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(df_pattern['x'], df_pattern['y'], color='green', width=0.4)   

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The little you've provided (which may be all they told you?) assumes prior knowledge of or familiarity with Python and/or MyBinder. If they didn't provide you that then perhaps they directed you to other materials and resources on their sites?

Here's how you'd accomplish this, I think, without the authors helping further:

1. [Click here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/materialsproject/binder/HEAD) to start up a temporary session that has all the necessary dependencies needed to run your provided code already installed.
2. Start a new notebook and enter your code. (Alternatively to have that code and further steps already be in a notebook, in the new notebook cell enter `!curl -OL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fomightez/8ef2f588965fbc10f19db79ee0035094/raw/778f399652a08a1f4be70400c5592c59e59cd876/demo_use_mp_api_with_MaterialsProject.ipynb`. Give it a few seconds to fetch that notebook file & then double-click that `demo_use_mp_api_with_MaterialsProject.ipynb` file that should now appear in the file browser panel on the left. Open that notebook and then select from the 'File menu' area > '`Run`' > '`Run All Cells`' and look there for the rest of what I write about here.)
3. I noted that it didn't didn't generate any files even though it said 'Retrieving MaterialsDoc documents'. So the contents retrieved must be among the Python objects now active, it seems.
4. To see what those are, I looked at the assigned variables and entered them as the last line in Jupyter notebook cells and ran those cells. Example, I entered in a cell the following:

```py
structure
```

Ran that cell and then I saw:

```
Structure Summary
Lattice
    abc : 7.086166087833533 7.086166087833533 8.514034991951231
 angles : 54.50319138768853 54.50319138768853 54.77885193228324
 volume : 264.22028210282747
      A : 3.259891 6.291809 0.0
      B : -3.259891 6.291809 0.0
      C : 0.0 5.567899 6.441063
    pbc : True True True
PeriodicSite: W (1.9253, 6.2918, 0.0000) [0.7953, 0.2047, 0.0000]
PeriodicSite: W (-1.9253, 6.2918, 0.0000) [0.2047, 0.7953, 0.0000]
PeriodicSite: Cl (0.0000, 13.1912, 5.4807) [0.6718, 0.6718, 0.8509]
PeriodicSite: Cl (0.0000, 7.1635, 5.2908) [0.2058, 0.2058, 0.8214]
PeriodicSite: Cl (1.7149, 10.5162, 4.5739) [0.7845, 0.2585, 0.7101]
PeriodicSite: Cl (-1.7149, 10.5162, 4.5739) [0.2585, 0.7845, 0.7101]
PeriodicSite: Cl (1.7149, 7.6353, 1.8672) [0.7415, 0.2155, 0.2899]
PeriodicSite: Cl (-1.7149, 7.6353, 1.8672) [0.2155, 0.7415, 0.2899]
PeriodicSite: Cl (0.0000, 10.9880, 1.1503) [0.7942, 0.7942, 0.1786]
PeriodicSite: Cl (0.0000, 4.9603, 0.9603) [0.3282, 0.3282, 0.1491]
```

I also did that with `pattern` and `conventional_structure`.
(Note that the last line in a Jupyter notebook cell is special in that the [REPL context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) will get used to evaluate and display the corresponding output whatever is on that line.)

5. What it shows in the output for those, you can select and copy and then make files back on your local machine by pasting the clipboard into your favorite code editor. For your needs maybe that is sufficient? If you read on, I describe how you can send the values assigned the variables to text files you can download without copying-pasting.
6. If you want to make text files from the contents assigned to each variable you can use [Jupyter/IPython %store magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) to send the values of the variables to a text file. I'll use `structure` as an example again. Enter the following in a cell to save the value of `pattern` to a text file.

```py
%store pattern >pattern.txt
```

You'll see `pattern.txt` show up in the file browser a few seconds later after it automatically updates. You can run `ls` in a cell if you don't want to wait. It should be listed among the files present in the current working directory.

7. **Anything that is made that is useful, you need to download from the temporary session before it times out.** So if you made the text files using step #6, you'll want to download those text files from the remote session back to your local machine. If you do this in a notebook, you may want to download that as well. For example, that's how I got [this](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/8ef2f588965fbc10f19db79ee0035094), which I optionally suggested you fetch and run in your session in step #2 above.
   To download the files showing in the file browser on the left, locate the files in the list, then right-click on them in the file browser to select them individually, and then from the menu that comes up select 'Download'. You'll be prompted as to where you want to save the files on your call machine.